Calling a method from gnome service via dbus
I want to contact gnome via dbus and use the Screenshot method from here https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/xdg-desktop-portal-gnome/-/blob/main/data/org.gnome.Shell.Screenshot.xml
I use the c API for this https://docs.gtk.org/gio/ctor.DBusProxy.new_sync.html
What do I need to specify in the parameters const gchar* name (bus name), const gchar* object_path, const gchar* interface_name?
As I understand it, the bus name should be org.gnome.Shell and the interface_name should be org.gnome.Shell.Screenshot It's right?
For example, when I used the Screenshot method from https://github.com/flatpak/xdg-desktop-portal/blob/main/data/org.freedesktop.portal.Screenshot.xml, I specified the bus name as org.freedesktop.portal.Desktop, object_path as /org/freedesktop/portal/desktop and interface_name org.freedesktop.portal.Screenshot
